# PHP MYSQL Inserting multiple data using arrays from table

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a problem with my code:

```
$size = count($_POST['tv_id']);
$size = count($_POST['Season']);
$size = count($_POST['EpisodeNumber']);
$size = count($_POST['EpisodeName']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $Season = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tv_id'][$i]);
    $Season = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Season'][$i]);
    $EpisodeNumber= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EpisodeNumber'][$i]);
    $EpisodeName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EpisodeName'][$i]);

    $sql="INSERT INTO tvshows SET fk_id = '".$fk_id."', tv_id ='".$tv_id."', Season ='".$Season."', EpisodeNumber='".$EpisodeNumber."', EpisodeName='".$EpisodeName."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 }
```

If i fill just one of my inputs in my form and hit submit it submits that one one but also 16 blank records with just the playlist_id and the other columns blank. If i filled in 5 columns it would submit them but also 11 blanks along with just the fk_id

My table layout is like this:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='tv_id[]' id='tv_id' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Season[]' id='Season[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeNumber[]' id='EpisodeNumber[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeName[]' id='EpisodeName[]' value='' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='tv_id[]' id='tv_id' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Season[]' id='Season[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeNumber[]' id='EpisodeNumber[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeName[]' id='EpisodeName[]' value='' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='tv_id[]' id='tv_id' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Season[]' id='Season[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeNumber[]' id='EpisodeNumber[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeName[]' id='EpisodeName[]' value='' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='tv_id[]' id='tv_id' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Season[]' id='Season[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeNumber[]' id='EpisodeNumber[]' value='' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='EpisodeName[]' id='EpisodeName[]' value='' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
```

and keeps going for about another 10.

Comment: And what's the problem ? You don't want to record empty rows ? So just test them like `if($Season && $EpisodeNumber ....) // Insert`BTW, you should `$size += ...`

Comment: You are aware that the first 4 lines of your PHP code are just overwriting the `$size` variable, right?

Comment: I want it so that if i leave a row blank it won't insert anything but right now its inserting blanks.

Comment: I believe that in your script, you will have an infinite while loop.  You never increase the value of `$i`.  Unless that part was left out, an error should be thrown because `$i` always = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why your are puting all counts in the same var size, but for empty records, you may do the following :

```
while ($i < $size) {
    $Season = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tv_id'][$i]);
    $Season = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Season'][$i]);
    $EpisodeNumber= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EpisodeNumber'][$i]);
    $EpisodeName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EpisodeName'][$i]);
    //....
    if(!empty($Season) and !empty($EpisodeNumber) and ...)
    {
    $sql="INSERT INTO tvshows SET fk_id = '".$fk_id."', tv_id ='".$tv_id."', Season ='".$Season."', EpisodeNumber='".$EpisodeNumber."', EpisodeName='".$EpisodeName."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $i++;  }
```

Comment: If you take a look at my answer I explain that you could use a 2d array to store everything in `$size`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have an if statement to validate your form wherever you have the php code for the form action.  You can use some variant of the code below.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($thisVar); $i++) {
    if(!empty($thisVar[$i])) {
        <insert query>
    }
}
```

$thisVar is the array where you store the inputs from the form and i would be the place in the  array where the value is stored.

As a side note, when you have `$size` defined multiple times in a row, the last one will be the only value.  You could do a 2D array if which case you would need another for loop with `$j` and the if statement would be in there with `$thisVar[$i][$j]`

Comment: That's right. Only insert data if your key fields are not empty. I'd recommend if(!empty($someVar)) instead of $someVar != ''.

Comment: That is a valid point, always used !=, but I think empty would be better.